# Problema con placeolder en foreach vista, laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

ando configurado un mensaje placeholder a un foreach en una vista.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('gobe_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <select name="gobe_id" id="gobe_id" class=" form-control" required>
                @foreach($governor as $item)
                <option placeholder="direccion" value="{{ $item->id }}" {{ $item->id === old('gobe_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}> {{$item->governor_candidate}}
                </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

            @if ($errors->has('gobe_id'))
            <span class="help-block">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('gobe_id') }}</strong>
             </span> @endif
        </div>
    </div>
```

Pero no funciona, si aplicara esta propiedad en un input de texto o numero funciona perfecto, pero con este select no he podido, es posible esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**placeholder** no es un atributo de `<option>` por lo tanto no te funciona.

Los atributos disponibles para `<option>` son:

- disabled
- label
- selected
- value

Fuente y mas detalles: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/option

Si quieres usar opciones adicionales, tendrás que usar alguna extensión; por ejemplo `Bootstrap-select`
https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/